# Join tables using a value inside a JSON column postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, hive

I have two tables in postgresql.

1. the first (product) has sku json row ([149461190])
2. the second (item) has an ordinary sku column

How can I join them on sku? I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
select * from product ps
, jsonb_to_recordset(ps.sku -> 'ps_sku') as (sku text)
join item v using sku
```

Exception I get

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 5:39 cannot
> recognize input near 'jsonb_array_elements_text' '(' 'p' in
> joinSourcePart

Comment: Please give a concrete and representative example of the ps.sku json data in table product, and give the data type of the column sku in table item.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that `product` is a table and this table has a field by name `sku` and by type JSON, and JSON has a key by name `ps_sku`

If the `ps_sku` key value is an integer type then:

```
select * from product pr 
inner join item itm on itm.sku = (pr.sku->'ps_sku')::integer
```

If the `ps_sku` key value is a text type then:

```
select * from product pr 
inner join item itm on itm.sku = (pr.sku->'ps_sku')::text
```

`pr.sku->'ps_sku'` this command extract value of `ps_sku` key from JSON string (from `sku` field)